# The browser does not read compiled from SASS to css file

Tags: html, css, web, sass

The browser does not read compiled from SASS to css file Failed to load resource: net :: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND style.% D1% 81ss.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.сss">
```

All files in one folder

Answer (score 0):

Oooops...I typed 'с' on russian